# Change banner instruction from miles to meter or km

Tags: android, sdk, mapbox

**Change distance display in banner instruction from mi or feet to km or meter**

I am following instruction in
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/

as i have my specific route, I try to develop a routing server as part of my own project, I am able to feed the routing json into directionsresponse object. The distance it self in banner instruction shows miles, while i am using meter as distance. I can change the distance in miles easily but that is not what i want to achieve.

Sorry, i havent try any code to change it as i have no idea where to start.

expected result will me like

```
150 meters
```

while now i have

```
150 mi
```

I understand that there is a question that similar, but the only answer is will be developed , and that was in 2017.

and i am not sure why people give -1 to this question.

I plan to release this project in the next 3 month in the github as a guide for beginner like me to develop a python base routing server.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for checking out the Navigation SDK!  For the `NavigationView`, distance formatting is based on the localization of the voice instructions in the `DirectionsRoute`.  Check out [this documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/localization/#voice-instruction-sources) for more details regarding this. Let us know if this helps!